# Por valor do select em uma variavel PHP: LARAVEL BLADE

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Estou tentando pegar o valor do select "categories" e por na variavel "$artigo" utilizando as blades do Laravel, mas não estou encontrando como fazer isto. Alguém consegue me dar uma luz?

```
   <?php
    $categories = DB::table('products')->select('category')->get(); 
    $categories = array_unique($categories, SORT_REGULAR);
    array_splice($categories, 0, 1); //exluindo os produtos que ainda não tem pategorias 
  
    ?>                                     
    <label class="control-label">Filtro:</label>
  <div class="">
    <a href="#" data-open-in="picker" data-picker-close-text="OK" data-back-on-select="true" class="item-link smart-select">
      <select  class="products_qto select-filter-cat"  name="categories" id="filter-cat" >
          <option selected>ARTIGOS</option>
          @foreach ($categories as $cat_item)
               <option value="{{$cat_item->category}}">{{$cat_item->category}}</option>
          @endforeach   
        </select> 
    </a>
  </div> 

  
  <?php 
  $artigo = '????';
   ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aparentemente você está um pouco confuso com o funcionamento do PHP. O PHP é uma linguagem server-side,ou seja, interpretada no servidor. Não tem forma de uma variável no PHP receber o valor de um select, que é renderizado no client-side.

O que você pode fazer é gerar um formulário, enviar o dado via POST e receber no controller. Além disso, não é recomendado criar variáveis na view. O que você pode fazer é criar no controller e repassar para a view.

Ex:

```
<form action="{{ route('minharota') }}" method="post">
<!-- minhaview.blade.php -->
@csrf
    <select name="meucampo">
        <option value="1"> Meu valor 1 </option>
        <option value="2"> Meu valor 2 </option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit"> Enviar form </button>
</form>
<h1>Valor: {{ $variavel ?? ' (O formulário ainda não foi enviado) ' }}

// controller

class MeuController 
{

    public function meuMetodo(Request $request)
    {
        $variavel = $request->meucampo;

        return view('minhaview')->with('variavel', $variavel);
    }
}

//routes.php
Route::post('minharota')->uses('MeuController@meuMetodo')->name('minharota');
```